# OpenGL – Get distance to farthest face from camera instead of closest face

Tags: opengl, graphics, pyopengl, depth-buffer

I'm using OpenGL (with Python bindings) to render depth maps of models saved as `.obj` files. The output is a numpy array with the depth to the object at each pixel.

The seemingly relevant parts of the code I'm using look like this:

```
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)                # The Type Of Depth Test To Do
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)             # Enables Depth Testing

... load the vertices and triangles, set the camera viewing position ...

depth = np.array(glReadPixels(0, 0, Width, Height, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT), dtype=np.float32)
```

I can use this to successfully render depth images of the object.

However, what I want to do is, instead of obtaining the depth of the face closest to the camera along each ray, **I want to obtain the depth of the face furthest from the camera**. I want faces to be rendered regardless of in which direction they are facing – i.e. I don't want to backface-cull.

I tried to achieve this by modifying the above code like so:

```
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)             # Turn off backface culling
glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER)             # The Type Of Depth Test To Do
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)             # Enables Depth Testing

... load the vertices and triangles, set the camera viewing position ...

depth = np.array(glReadPixels(0, 0, Width, Height, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT), dtype=np.float32)
```

However, when I do this I don't get any depth at all rendered. I suspect that this is because I am using `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` to read out the depth, however I am not sure what to change to fix this.

How can I get the depth of the faces furthest from the camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching the depth test to `GL_GREATER` in priciple will do the trick, you overlooked just a tiny detail: You need to initialize the depth buffer differently. By default, it will be intialized to 1.0 when clearing the depth buffer, so that `GL_LESS` comparisions might update it to values smaller than 1.0.

Now, you want it to work the other way around, so you must intialize it to 0.0. To do so, just add a [`glClearDepth`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glClearDepth.xml)`(0.0f)` before the `glClear(... | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`.

Furthermore, you yourself mention that you don't want backface culling for that. But instead of disabling that you can also switch the face culling around using [`glCullFace`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glCullFace.xml). You probably want `GL_FRONT` here, as `GL_BACK` is the default. But disabling it will work too, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use `glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);` to enable depth writing to the buffer.

Comment: Thanks, I added this but it didn't make any difference. I think that depth writing must be enabled by default – I am able to successfully get the depths to the closest faces after all.

Comment: When you try your second method, do you actually get geometry drawing on the screen?  Make sure that the depth buffer is all set to zero first before attempting this, I suspect your second method doesn't work simply because none of the current geometry can validly draw on the screen since the default depth is 1.0 and you only accept values greater than that.

Comment: Yes the problem was depth buffer not set to zero to begin with – as suggested by @derhass